# Using Remove event to detect the model removed from the collection in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

My question is , is there a way to detect the model that got removed from the collection when we bind/listen to the collection's add Event.

for ex:

```
this.listenTo(monthsOnBoardCollection, "remove", function(){
  //is it possible here to find what got removed from the collection ? 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) which shows the arguments being passes to the event.

```
"remove" (model, collection, options) — when a model is removed from a collection.
```

So it's basically:

```
this.listenTo(monthsOnBoardCollection, "remove", function(model, collection, options){
  //now you have the model, the collection and the options which were passed to the remove method
}
```